# How to return value of a MATLAB function with different inputs in parallel?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

I have my own MATLAB function which is complex and takes around 100 seconds to run for a given input. For 10 inputs serially it would take around 100*10 = 1000 seconds. I have tried using arrayfun and for loops and both take around the same time of around 1000 seconds. Is there a method in MATLAB to parallelize the operation over 10 inputs such that the overall operation amounts to around 100 seconds. This would because all operations are done parallely. Kindly explain. I have a GPU in my PC.

Here is a snippet of my code of the complex function (I am not giving the gory details ) :

```
function [out] = myComplexFunction(input)
    %% Some Data pre-processing code
    [out]=someOptimizer(processedInput); % This optimization is the most time-consuming step
end
```

My goal is to parallely compute the `myComplexFunction()` over 10 instances of the input. Kindly help me out.

Comment: The [Parallel Computing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing.html) might do this for you; however, could there be ways to speed up your code through vectorization?

Comment: Could you be more specific what function and tool to use in the parallel computing toolbox ? I have tried parfor, arrayfun, batch but of no avail.

Comment: what is your problem with `parfor`?

Comment: the code for your function might help in identifying the problem. Consider adding it to your question

Comment: Yes, I have added a skeleton of the code.

Comment: Note that you may not be able to perform the 10 operations in 100 seconds as you normally don't have that many CPU cores.

Comment: How about if I have a GPU ?

Comment: You only have one GPU, so you can't run 10 different things at once on it. You would have to vectorize your code so that all 10 inputs are processed in the same commands. Which may not be possible of course.

Comment: @Buna - If you show us your code for the 'someOptimizer' function, we may be able to suggest ways to vectorize it and speed it up.